# Read REF type node of a OpenCV generated YML file

Tags: python, opencv, yaml

I tried to read node in a YML file. There I checked node type. Which is 4. According to the [type chart](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/dd9/classcv_1_1FileNode.html#aeac30395ae3473911171a2091c6ab74c), It maps into The `REF` type. I referred this [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d74/tutorial_file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html),   Under that I haven't seen way to read data of `REF` type node . Any help is appreciated to read my node. Thank you.

```
import cv2
fs = cv2.FileStorage("ProjectorParameters.yml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.getNode("FeaturesValue")
print (fn.type ()) # 4 
print (fn.isSeq ()) # True
```

The yml file that I wanna read.

```
%YAML:1.0
---
zThreshold: 40.
FeaturesValue: [ 13, 15, 25, 7, 27, 19, 31, 23, 29, 31, 13, 15, 25, 7 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses Referencing therefore I used iterative way . Hope it helps to X

```
for i in range(fn.size()):
   print(fn.at(i).real())
```